# How to access a shared prefrences create in flutter from java code?

Tags: android, flutter

I create a SharedPreferences in flutter and I want to use it in android Native code in my project. How can I do that?

Comment: can you please explain bit more

Comment: like this https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences

Comment: can you please add some of you code also?

Comment: I create sharedPreferences in my dart file. I have function in java file on main folder, which run a service. I want to access that sharedPreferences key in android

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For the noobs out here,

```
import android.content.SharedPreferences
...
var PRIVATE_MODE = 0
val mPrefs = getSharedPreferences("FlutterSharedPreferences", PRIVATE_MODE)
mPrefs.getString("flutter." + "key", "")
```

Comment: Just a note as this answer is "popular." It's better to use the module's PRIVATE_MODE variable than to self-set, although I personally did not do that since it was not worth digging around where that variable was even set.

Answer (score 11):

Add this to your code. It will work.

```
SharedPreferences mPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences("FlutterSharedPreferences", context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String value = mPrefs.getString("flutter." + "YourSharedpreferencekey", "");
```

Answer (score 3):

Dart sharedPreference use [native java code](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/shared_preferences/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/sharedpreferences/SharedPreferencesPlugin.java) which means they are using the same sharedPreferences, you can access that sharedPreferences key in Android by calling sharedPreferences from native code (Java or Kotlin).

Answer (score 3):

Step By Step

1st Flutter Part

here you assign a value

```
Future<SharedPreferences> _prefs = SharedPreferences.getInstance();

final SharedPreferences prefs = await _prefs;
  await prefs.setString("SharedPrefKey", definition)
```

then you can use it in flutter where ever you want

```
String stringFromShared;

Future<SharedPreferences> _prefs = SharedPreferences.getInstance();

stringFromShared = prefs.getString("SharedPrefKey");
```

2nd Android Part

```
private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;


sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("FlutterSharedPreferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    sharedPreferences.getString("flutter." + "SharedPrefKey", "");
```

the key point here is usage of prefix "flutter."